# drupal 7: mail does sent but body and subject are empty

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am trying sending email with Drupal 7. The email is sent to my email account but somehow the body and subject is empty. Please help me to explain why. Thank you very much.

Below is my code:

This is the form

```
function get_friendform($form,&$form_submit){
    $form['fullname'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Your Full Name: '),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#size' => 30,
    );

    $form['email'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Your Full Email: '),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#size' => 30,
    );

    $form['friend_email'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Your Friend Email: '),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#size' => 30,
    );


    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'submit',
        '#submit' => array('sendform_form_submit')

    );

    return $form;
}



function sendform_form_submit($form,&$form_submit){
    $fullname = $form_submit['values']['fullname'];
    $email = $form_submit['values']['email'];
    $friend_email = $form_submit['values']['friend_email'];
    $current_page = $GLOBALS['base_url'] .'/'.current_path();

    $mailto = 'thelinhuk@gmail.com';
    $mailfrom = 'thelinhuk@yahoo.com';
    $subject = "Links to event";
    $body = $current_page;
    $params = array(
        'body' => $body,
        'subject' => $subject,
    );

    if (drupal_mail('get_friendform', 'send_link', $mailto, language_default(),$params,$mailfrom,TRUE)) {
        drupal_set_message(t('Your message was sent successfully!!!'));
    }

}



function sendform_mail($key,&$message,$params) {
    $language = $message['language'];
    switch ($key) {
        case 'send_link':
            $message['subject']=t($params['subject'], $var, $language->language);
            $message['body'][]=$params['body'];
            $message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed';
        break;
    }

}
```

Thank you very much

new code

```
function sendform_form_submit($form,&$form_submit){
    $fullname = $form_submit['values']['fullname'];
    $email = $form_submit['values']['email'];
    $friend_email = $form_submit['values']['friend_email'];
    $current_page = $GLOBALS['base_url'] .'/'.current_path();

    $mailto = 'thelinhuk@gmail.com';
    $mailfrom = 'thelinhuk@yahoo.com';
    $subject = "Links to event";
    $params ='';
    $body[] = $current_page;
    $mail_message = drupal_mail('send_form', 'some_key', $mailto, language_default(), $params, $mailfrom, TRUE);
    $mail_message['subject'] = $subject;
    $mail_message['body'] = $body;

    $mail_system = drupal_mail_system($module, $key);
    $mail_message = $mail_system->format($mail_message);

    $mail_message['result'] = $mail_system->mail($mail_message);

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following code example to send emails using drupal:

```
$body = array();
$body[] = "Mail body";
$mail_message = drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, $lang, $params, $from, $send);
$mail_message['subject'] = $subject;
$mail_message['body'] = $body;

$mail_system = drupal_mail_system($module, $key);
$mail_message = $mail_system->format($mail_message);

$mail_message['result'] = $mail_system->mail($mail_message);
```

Update 1:

There's a problem in your code. You have created a function `sendform_mail()` and you never called it.

You can use the code example above inside the form submission callback `sendform_form_submit()`. This is much simpler

Update 2:

```
$mail_message = drupal_mail('send_form', 'some_key', $mailto, language_default(), $params, $mailfrom, TRUE);
```

In your code, change the last value to `false`, because you need to stall the mail sending till the last line `$mail_message['result']`.

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Comment: hi, thank you very much. but with which function should i use the code in. Thanks

Comment: hi, thanks i have implemented. It works, however it gives me one correct email and one extra empty email. I included the code above into send_form_form_submit() and removed the send form_mail()

Comment: Do you have any idea why it sends an empty email

Comment: i have updated my post .. the new code is at the bottom .. Thank you very much