# Drupal simple mail sending with cc and bcc

Tags: email, drupal-7

I have gone through the [drupal_mail](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) function and written the below code. It is sending the mail but without the subject and Body of mail.

Can anyone tell me why is it so. Other part is how can I add CC and BCC in mail?

Gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251479/drupal-7-mail-does-sent-but-body-and-subject-are-empty) but they have not used drupal_mail in answer

```
$params = array(
    'body' => 'plain text mail',
    'subject' => 'Join this Event',
);

if(drupal_mail('join_this_event', 'some_mail_key', "ansari@infiniti-research.com", language_default(), $params, "noreply@test.com", TRUE)){
    echo "mail sent";
}
else echo "unable to send";
```

Comment: Anyone knows why this is happening ?

Answer (score 2):

Everything you need is in the email message headers array.

```
$params['headers'] = array(
    'Bcc' => 'bcc_email@example.com',
    'Cc' => 'cc_email@example.com',
);
```

Here is an example implementation of drupal_mail() with bcc headers included.

```
$params = array(
    'body' => $body,
    'subject' => $subject,
    'headers' => array(
        'Bcc' => $header_bcc,
        'Cc' => $header_cc
    )
);

$email = drupal_mail('ModuleName', 'message_key', $to, LANGUAGE_NONE, $params, $from, true);
```

Using hook_mail():

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail().
 */
function ModuleName_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
    switch ($key) {
        case 'message_key':
            $message['headers'] += $params['headers'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Monty. I tried your answer but still it is not sending mail to cc and bcc, also mail is going without body as before.